# CakePHP 3 - sql statement string to query object

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Is there a way to convert an sql string to a query object?

I have a complicated SQL statement as a string. Later I would join with a query object.

So i would need to convert my SQL string to a query object.

Comment: I think if you want to get useful answers, you'll need to be more specific about what your complicated SQL looks like, and what kind of query you would want to be joining it to. It sounds like you are thinking of something more than what `ConnectionManager::get('default')->execute('complex SQL statement here')` would do for you.

Comment: json_decode() maybe ?